# Teechart marks on Stacked Chart

Tags: activex, teechart

Is there any way we can make data more readable when we perform Stacked operation on series.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is *Series.Marks.AutoPosition* property for that. It's going to be deprecated soon and replaced by *Series.Marks.Automatic.Move*.

This property has been implemented for the TeeChart VCL/FMX version so far, the version from which TeeChart ActiveX is derived as a COM wrapper. Also note this property is not yet handled by all series styles. So far it is used by Map and World series.

The intention of “Automatic” is to perform several attempts to avoid series marks overlap other marks or other parts of the chart. It is True by default in all sub-properties.

In the meantime you can implement anti-overlapping similar to what was suggested [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?t=560). This is a TeeChart for .NET thread but same principles apply to all versions.

Comment: till when can we expect the same feature for the bar chart in ActiveX controller

Comment: @AkshayBhalla it may take some time since the last maintenance release was published a few weeks ago: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15003.